Implement non-generic method on generic type in Go?
I'm building my own data structures that contains a buffer of any type T. I then tried implementing some methods on the type, as you would.
type Test[T any] struct {
    buf []T
}

func (t *Test[T]) WorksFine(v) {
    t.buf = append(t.buf, v)
}

Implementing methods that still use the same constraint T work fine. Go even allows declaring a signature that instantiates T to a concrete type, at least so it seems.
func (t *Test[byte]) StillWorks() string {
    return fmt.Sprint(t)
}

Note that byte isn't really used in the body but at least Intellisense recognizes that it should only suggest (*Test[byte]).StillWorks on Tests constrained by byte.
Probably, however, you're narrowing the type because you want to perform some operation based on the concrete type that wouldn't be possible in a generic context. Here's where Go fails:
func (t *Test[byte]) String() string {
    return string(t.vals)
}

This raises an error cannot convert t.vals (variable of type []byte/* type parameter */) to type string (InvalidConversion). Of course, a type constraint isn't the same a concrete type but shouldn't there be some way of telling Go that I want a method to only work on Test[T].
Am I overengineering things? Is the solution to move all byte methods out into functions in the package space?
PS: I'd totally accept it, if Go didn't let me do any constraints at all. But the fact that the StillWorks method is legal, made me raise an eyebrow.

Your code
func (t *Test[byte]) StillWorks() string {
    return fmt.Sprint(t)
}

doesn't say "this method requires T to be byte". Your code says "I have decided to name this type parameter byte".
Even though you've picked the name byte, and even though this isn't the same name T you picked earlier, your byte type parameter can be instantiated with any type that fits the any constraint.
So, for example, this works:
var x Test[int64]
fmt.Print(x.StillWorks())

I don't think Go actually has a way to write methods that only exist for certain instantiations of a generic type. The docs don't mention anything like that.
